# How to find a string that starts with number using egrep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want find a words that starts with number for example 6.1234, 4times, 4-times, 6, 68 .. i tried this: egrep -n "(^[0-9].*)" file.txt

Comment: And what were your results?

Comment: it wont find words in the middle of line

Comment: Give us an example of your input file

Comment: input file :
something 6.1234 somethng
something 18.11.1995 something
something 6times something 6-times something
something 6 something 68 something

Comment: @SamuelJurek we cannot tell how your input is formatted from comments... add it to question along with expected output and see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Also give an example of the expected output. I think the word `18.11.1995` ands at the first dot and should return `18`. Should `6-times` return `6`? And "words" with `!?@#$%^&*' in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
grep -ow '[0-9][^ ]*'
```

Comment: How about TAB between words? Do you think `?*&!$` are all part of the word sarting with `[0-9]`?

Comment: yes you are right, it's better with [[:blank:]]. for ?*&!$, I don't know, I'm not the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
~'^[0-9]'
```

It will return results start with digits.

Comment: it wont work in this Input file (input file : something 6.1234 somethng something 18.11.1995 something something 6times something 6-times something something 6 something 68 something) it doesnt return anything